# Pulling variable from html within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to pull an html variable from an iframe which is inside another div inside the iframe.

Here is the excerpt of the code I'm using:

```
var myVariable = $('#iframe-id').contents().find('.variable-inside').html();
```

The iframe has been give an id (#iframe-id) and the variable is inside "variable-inside" which is rendered inside the iframe.

For some reason this isn't working for me. Is there a problem with the code?

I'm aware this method can be used if both documents are on the same domain (iframe doc and other doc) but I can still use it if it's on the same domain, just different subdomains correct? Eg: iframe doc is at lorem.example.com and other doc is at ipsum.example.com)

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Communication across sub-domains is not allowed (Cross-Domain-Policy), I've read about ways to get around it but have not tested these.

Here's one method: http://www.tomhoppe.com/index.php/2008/03/cross-sub-domain-javascript-ajax-iframe-etc/

The idea is to set `document.domain = "yourdomain.com"` on both the parent and child pages (untested).

Comment: If push comes to shove, create a server-side proxy for the sub-domain-hosted-file. It would just grab the HTML from the external document and echo it out so you can access cross-domain data.

Comment: It worked! Just added `<script type="text/javascript">
   document.domain = 'example.com';
  </script>` to each page and it worked fine. Thank you.

Comment: it looks interesting, do you know if it works cross-domain ( not only sub-cross-domain ) ?

Comment: I don't have the time to test right now but if anyone has access to two domains it'd be pretty easy to test :)

Comment: @pawlakppp Just searched and found this: http://jszen.blogspot.com/2005/03/cross-domain-security-woes.html It appears it can work but has some issues with security and browsers. EDIT: Actually being 7 years old it is probably not the best source.